# Is there a list of browser rendering bugs?

Tags: html, css, browser

I have found some sites via Google but would like to know if anyone has a list of browser rendering bugs that is either available to view online or is downloadable?

Comment: Even if there was it wouldn't be very helpful. Open your website in all the browsers you need to support. Just test.

Comment: I was more looking for a way to learn about the potential pit falls before writing the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Chromium bugs: http://crbug.com (Chromium is the open-source browser that underlies Chrome)
- [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/) bugs: https://bugs.webkit.org (the rendering engine used by Chrome and Safari)
- Firefox bugs: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org

Safari, Internet Explorer and [Opera](https://bugs.opera.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa) do not share their issue tracking with the general public, as they are proprietary, closed-source software.

---

Not *exactly* a list of bugs, but possibly more useful to you regardless:

- [Quirksmode compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html)
- [Can I use... Compatibility tables](http://caniuse.com/)

As these are constantly-evolving, complex pieces of software, this information changes somewhat frequently.

Comment: Thanks Matt, this answered the question well.